# Convert Rally user stories into tasks

Tags: rally

I had a user that created a bunch of 'stories' in rally when they really should of been tasks. Is there a way to convert user stories into tasks in Rally? I've searched through Rally's help site but it doesn't appear to offer an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Rally only defects can be converted to user stories: no other work item type conversion is possible.

Comment: It seems to be useful to be able to convert a use story to defect but rally can't do it atm.